# C# WPF not rendering all rectangles

Tags: c#, wpf

So essentially I have 4 red rectangles with rounded corners that are supposed to show up when I run the application. The code for all 4 is nearly identical.  **The problem is only the first 2 show up. And the 2nd one is clipped off at the end.**

There are no errors, no compile or runtime exceptions just simply not showing up.

Here is my WPF code

```
<Window x:Class="flashing_colors.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1200" Width="1800">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="700" RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25" Name="rect1" Margin="-400,184,800,185"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="700" RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25" Name="rect2" Margin="600,184,990,185"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="700" RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25" Name="rect3" Margin="1000,184,800,185"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="700" RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25" Name="rect4" Margin="1400,184,800,185"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my C# code.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           rect1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(225, 75, 75));
           rect2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(225, 75, 75));
           rect3.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(225, 75, 75));
           rect4.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(225, 75, 75));
       }
   }
```

Here is a screenshot of what it shows. Notice only 2 rounded rectangles.
[image: 2 out of 4 rectangles showing up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you set Margin Left to 1000 and Right to 800 all width of windows is set to 1800 so it has no space to display it, change 800 to 500 for third rectangle and so on for third. I suggest using StackPanel with Horizontal orientation instead of playing with Margin.

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="700"/>
            <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="CadetBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Rectangle Name="rect1"/>
    <Rectangle Name="rect2"/>
    <Rectangle Name="rect3"/>
    <Rectangle Name="rect4"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I will give that a try for sure.  Margins was how VS defaulted to set their position when dragging them in designer.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett Which is why I *never* user the VS designer to adjust layout. I only use it to see how a control will render - so I don't have to keep re-compiling the app.